# Cognos Analytics 11.x - Find database vendor type in a query subject definition

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11, cognos-8

I want to find the data source vendor oracle or sql or DB2 on a query subject definition.How to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lineage tool if the data sources are named properly.  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=vlidi-cognos-analytics-lineage-tool

Alternatively you can create a calculation with a bogus function and examine the error stack.  For example an expression of add_spare(current_date) causes the following error:

XQE-DAT-0001 Data source adapter error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: No authorized routine named "ADD_SPARE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=3.72.54
RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back:

Which tells you the data source is DB2